# Keeping Project JAR Files Up To Date

Tags: java, jar

When using multiple APIs in a single project, the JAR files required for each API are added to the project in addition to other needed libraries such as Apache Commons, logging, etc. that are already used by the project. This sometimes results in a large number of jar files.

When a certain API or library is no longer used, it would be nice to remove the JAR files associated with it. However, there is a risk that another API or library requires it. This would NOT always become apparent during the building of the project. Sometimes, JARs that are missing throw errors only at runtime.

I have the following questions:

1. What is the best way to deal with this issue? In other words, be able to remove JARs without running the risk of runtime errors later?
2. I have been told that Maven solves this problem. Does it? Would it work if the external APIs used are not Maven-based? Would I be able to remove JARs without worrying about runtime errors? Do I need to rewrite my entire project to be based on Maven?
3. How do non-JVM platforms deal with the issue of shared libraries and removing them? Is Java lacking in this area or it is a common issue for all platforms?

Comment: maven does have this ability

Comment: I'm not 100% clear: are you asking about adding and removing dependencies as part of the compile step, i.e. all libraries and dependencies in place at the start of execution, or adding and removing dependencies at runtime e.g. as part of loading and unloading plugins? Maven does do the first case, yes; if it's the plug-in case then you can achieve that using e.g. OSGi.

Comment: @Rup It is the first case I was asking about. I wasn't even aware you can load JARS during runtime. Where would you load them from if they are not included in your web app's lib directory?

Comment: Sorry, I'd missed that it was a web app. You probably wouldn't use that for a web app, no (although [Apache Sling](http://sling.apache.org/) is a web framework built on [Felix](http://felix.apache.org/) which will do just that for you). You can load other jar from anywhere, I think - just add them to the classpath in your existing classloader object or create a new classloader. But if you're in e.g. JBoss or Tomcat then it's probably safest not to mess with the container's classloader and just stick to your own .jars in the lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I agree Maven could help you in this case. Basically in Maven compile & runtime dependencies for each artifact (jar/war/ear/etc) are declared on pom.xml file. If multiple dependencies depends on same artifacts the latest version is used -- for example:

```
A-1.0.jar -- depends on --> C-2.0.jar
B-1.0.jar -- depends on --> C-2.1.jar
```

Only C-2.1.jar is is included in your project.

If a required dependency couldn't be found / taken out, Maven build will automatically fail. So to avoid runtime dependency missing, you can declare a dependency in runtime scope to a particular artifact -- and when you no longer need it you just take it out

Comment: I will learn and probably use Maven in my projects. Before I do, I have a question: Could I use an existing API that does not use Maven into my project in addition to ones that use Maven? How would the JARs for that API get integrated?

Comment: Yes, you just need to write up its dependencies in Maven's pom.xml format and then install the .pom and the .jar into your local Maven cache [`mvn install:install-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) and then Maven will take it from there. But chances are any dependency you didn't write yourself will have a Maven POM - it's very popular. Try Googling for your library and maven or have a look inside the .jar - the .pom is often packaged in a subdirectory of META-INF.

Answer (score 0):

There is an old trick I used to use on UNIX many years ago, it might still work for you. First use UNIX "touch" to set the date/time on all your files to the current date/time. Then wait for at least one minute. Then run your application. Then run UNIX "ls -lut" to list all your files, but this time the ones that were not used will have the date/time set in the first step whereas those that were used will have a more recent date/time due to the "u" switch reporting the last used date/time.

Comment: What if the library is not used during runtime until much later? Would this technique still work?

Comment: @stepanian a jar file is formatted just like a zip file so you have to open the jar file to extract any of its contents. The JVM will check the class path for the jar file's existence during initialization even if a different class loader is used to load files inside the jar file. Thus the last used time for the jar file will be updated.